# What is army count of commander in Warzone?

Tags: warzone

What is army count of commander in Warzone and how much army strength is needed to kill him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commander is worth 7 armies.

Thus he kills 4 while attacking in a normal game and needs to be attacked by 11 to be killed. If you commander is killed, You lose, and all of you territories become neutral.